# How to intergrate a funtion with high accuracy

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I am trying to integrate the product of functions of *sin* and *cos*. The results I am getting match when the result has a relatively large magnitude (e.g. `1e-2`~`1e-4`). But the results with small magnitude (e.g. `1e-11`~`1e-32`) have large relative error and are sometimes of opposite sign.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

# Define the integrand function
def f0(x,n):
    if n == 1:
        return (1-x)
    elif n == 2:
        return x
    else:
        return np.sin((n - 2) * np.pi * x)


def f00(x, m, n):
    return f0(x,m)*f0(x,n)

# Define the dimensions of the tensor
NMHT_0 = 12

# Create the tensor
I00 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))

# Perform the integration
for m in range(NMHT_0):
    for n in range(NMHT_0):
        result1, error1 = spi.quad(f00, 0, 1, args=(m, n))
        
        
        I00[m, n] = result1
```

I tried to integrate first with the [`scipy.integrate.quad_vec`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html) function, but all the small numbers are not matching. I replaced the `quad_vec` function with the [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) function, and it managed to get some of the small numbers to match, but the majority of the small numbers still do not match. Any way to get more accurate results, or should I try a different library?

Comment: Values on that order are approaching (or exceeding) machine precision, so you will not get accurate computations with those numbers. In other words, those values, for all intents and purposes, are 0.

Comment: `return f0(x,m)*f0(x,n)` Is this a typo? The function f1 is not referenced anywhere.

Comment: @NickODell If you look at their previous question you'll see that they also have `f01`, `f10`, and `f11` that make use of `f1`. They seem to have forgotten to remove it from this shortened example.

Comment: If you need "better precision", use `decimal` and set the context precision to something high like 20 or 30. But if you need true precision: don't use Python. Use a real maths programming language (but one that can be tied into a larger python program if that's what you need)

Comment: To follow up on that, you can use Sympy to compute the integral analytically, assuming there is an analytical solution. But you should also think about the theory. The integral of `sin(n*x)*sin(m*x)` is 0 when `n` and `m` are not equal. Same for `cos` (if I remember correctly). You can use that to build the matrix without actually integrating. In general, the fastest way to compute something in code is to know the solution in advance, which you do. Looking at this problem, I don't really see any reason to use quadrature.

Comment: @LutzLehmann what a bizarre take. No of course I'm not talking about C++ or Fortran (both of which have the same problem as Python itself), but a real maths programming language like Mathematica, Sage, etc. or a python package that acts as a maths programming interface. If you're doing integration, use the things that do that symbolically so that your final result is not based on compound numerical errors. As for "should that not be accuracy": if you need higher precision decimals because IEEE floats dont have enough digits, you use `decimal` and set its context's `prec` property.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Symbolic integration is almost never possible, except in the usual textbook examples and some interesting corner cases. // If you mean CAS, say CAS. // `decimal` should be used for financial computation, `mpmath` for multi-precision numerical computation. // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Programmers_Don%27t_Use_Pascal, https://www.ecb.torontomu.ca/~elf/hack/realmen.html

Comment: If you wanted to suggest `mpmath`, next time probably a better idea to just do that, instead of ignoring the [code of conduct](/conduct) and deriding someone in the comments. And if you do have to call someone out, be civil about it.

Answer (score 1):

The results are already accurate. You could try using the `epsrel` and `epsarg` arguments of [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) to try to get those small magnitude numbers closer to zero, but they are theoretically zero, so what you're seeing is a little numerical noise.

As suggested in the comments, [`mpmath.quad`](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/integration.html) can be used for arbitrary precision numerical integration in Python (when you need it).

```py
import numpy as np
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 100  # set the precision

# Define the integrand function
def f0(x, n):
    if n == 1:
        return (mp.one - x)
    elif n == 2:
        return x
    else:
        return mp.sin((n - 2) * mp.pi * x)

def f00(x, m, n):
    return f0(x, m) * f0(x, n)

# Define the dimensions of the tensor
NMHT_0 = 12

# Create the tensor
I00 = np.zeros((NMHT_0, NMHT_0))

# Perform the integration
for m in range(NMHT_0):
    for n in range(NMHT_0):        
        I00[m, n] = mp.quad(lambda x: f00(x, m, n), (0, 1), method='tanh-sinh')
        # I00[m, n] = mp.quad(lambda x: f00(x, m, n), (0, 1), method='gauss-legendre')
```

To be more confident that the precision is high enough, you can take a look for agreement between the two `method`s of `mpmath.quad` and check for convergence as `mp.dps` is increased.

But as @jared notes, this does not require numerical integration. We can use [`sympy.integrate`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html) (or look at a calculus textbook) to see that those tiny values are really zero.

```py
from sympy import integrate, symbols, sin, pi
m, n = symbols('m, n', positive=True, integer=True)
x = symbols('x')
integrate(sin(m*pi*x) * sin(n*pi*x), (x, 0, 1))
```

[image]